# sniffing a flash file to see where it tries to connect (host and port)

Tags: packet-sniffers

I hope i'm posting to the right forum (maybe it should have gone to superuser but i'm not sure).

I want to be able to see all the hosts and ports that a specific application is trying to connect to, in this scenario it's a flash file.

It's something very old that i wrote a few years and I forgot the address of the server that this flash file is trying to connect to using RTMP protocol on port 1936.  is there a way to sniff it some how ?

Comment: Have you tried [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/)?

Comment: wireshark is a bit complicated for me. no idea how to filter outgoing connections. i'll try to google that. thanks

Comment: A simple solution is to close all programs except Wireshark and the one you want to test. Also connecting to a low traffic network may help, such as tethering your computer to a cell phone.